# Java Socket not sending message to the server

Tags: java, socket.io

I have the following client socket for sending a string to the server. The server is not getting message. What could be the prob;em?

```
public void startClient() throws IOException {

    Socket socket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    InetAddress host = null;
    BufferedReader stdIn = null;

    try {
        host = InetAddress.getByName("172.16.2.97");
        socket = new Socket(host, 52000);

        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fromServer;
        String fromUser = null;
        //ClientHelper.unpackISO();
        fromUser = ClientHelper.createISO();
        if (fromUser != null) {
            //System.out.println("Client - " + fromUser);
            out.write(fromUser);
            System.out.println("Sent message");
        }


        while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Server - " + fromServer);
            if (fromUser != null) {
                //System.out.println("Client - " + fromUser);
                out.println(fromUser);
            }
        }
    } catch (ISOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot find the host: " + host.getHostName());
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't read/write from the connection: " +            e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    } finally { //Make sure we always clean up
        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

The method ClientHelper.createISO() return a string which is supposed to be sent to the server. Unfortunately the server is not getting any string. Could the problem be proxy settings. If so how can solve it. Or is it another problem with my code?
What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Can you receive from the Server?

Comment: whats the error you are getting any exception stack trace.

Comment: How does the server know it has received all the string?

Comment: I don't get any exception. I just don't get any message on the server

Answer (score 1):

You must flush() the stream after writing to it. Sockets buffer until you get a full packet otherwise

Comment: By using: out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true); true means that printwriter will be automatically flushed

Comment: Which does not autoflush the write() method.... from the documentation: autoFlush - A boolean; if true, the println, printf, or format methods will flush the output buffer

Answer (score 1):

Check the 5th line below, you need to flush your output stream. Otherwise server will not get any packet and you will stuck on your first in.readLine() because its blocking.

```
    fromUser = ClientHelper.createISO();
    if (fromUser != null) {
        //System.out.println("Client - " + fromUser);
        out.write(fromUser);
        out.flush(); // FLUSH IT HERE, packet wont be sent until you flush your stream
        System.out.println("Sent message");
    }
```

Also add flush after your out.write(fromUser) inside the loop.

Comment: I have tried that but still not working. This socket only works if i use my local machine as the server. But does not work if it is another machine

Comment: Did you get "Sent message" msg printed on client program?

Comment: "Sent message" will never be printed as `fromUser` will always be `null` before reading from the console. I don't see the point of the if statement in the try block. You also said "I just don't get any message on the server", have you verified that the client does actually connect to the server? Also, before `out.write(fromUser);` and `out.flush();`, have `out.write("\r\n")`